# do I need to make two clones of my data to make my listView Filterable

Tags: android, memory-management

```
  public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> Data) {

            OriginalData = Data;

            // ask stack overflow : is it the right solution
            FilteredData = (ArrayList<Item>) Data.clone();
    }
}
```

I need to make two clones of my data to make my listView filterable 
is it the best solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable textFilter on the list view so when the user types a letter, anything items beginning with whatever letter(s) they typed are shown.

```
getListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am using this but this is not my question

Comment: I think you may need to add more details of what you are trying to achieve then. If you're already using this to filter the data, why do you need to duplicate it

Comment: because I want to keep instance of the original data

Comment: Using textFilterEnabled doesn't modify the contents of the adapter. You can just display a menu to clear the filter and restore the list view back to how it was using ``getListView().clearTextFilter();``